# Perpendicular Chord parabola

Tags: conic-sections

If $r_1,r_2$ be the length of the perpendicular chords drawn through the vertex of a parabola $y^2=4ax$, then show that
$$(r_1r_2)^{4/3}=16a^2(r_1^{2/3}+r_2^{2/3})$$

Comment: Thanks for editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $O=(0,0)$ be the vertex of the parabola, and $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$, $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$, the other endpoints of the chords. The perpendicularity condition yields 
$$
y_1y_2=-x_1x_2=-{1\over16a^2}y_1^2y_2^2,
\quad\hbox{that is}\quad
y_1y_2=-16a^2
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
x_1x_2=16a^2.
$$
We have then:
$$
r_2^2=x_2^2+y_2^2=x_2^2+4ax_2={256a^4\over x_1^2}+{64a^3\over x_1}=
{64a^3\over x_1^3}(4ax_1+x_1^2)={64a^3\over x_1^3}(y_1^2+x_1^2)
=\left({4a\over x_1}\right)^3r_1^2
$$
that is
$$
r_2^{2/3}={4a\over x_1}r_1^{2/3}.
$$
It follows that
$$
r_1^{4/3}r_2^{4/3}={16a^2\over x_1^2}r_1^{8/3}
$$
and
$$
r_1^{2/3}+r_2^{2/3}=\left(1+{4a\over x_1}\right)r_1^{2/3}
={x_1^2+4ax_1\over x_1^2}r_1^{2/3}
={r_1^2\over x_1^2}r_1^{2/3}={1\over x_1^2}r_1^{8/3}.
$$
In conclusion:
$$
{r_1^{4/3}r_2^{4/3}\over r_1^{2/3}+r_2^{2/3}}=16a^2.
$$

Comment: In the first line, why is $x_1x_2=-\frac {1}{16a^2} y_1^2y_2^2$?

Comment: @Aditya I used the equation of the parabola: $x=y^2/(4a)$.